# Примеры написания кастомного executor'a и планировщика для boost.asio

Tags: c++, асинхронность, c++17, c++20, boost.asio

Откуда взять пример реализации кастомного executor'a и планировщика для boost.asio. Описание api, какой интерфейс должны реализовывать эти классы и тд?